# Codename one Map keeps causing exception?

Tags: android, exception, codenameone

I am trying to use the NativeMap on codename one , I followed the steps but when I try to use it , an exception occur and the application get stuck for a while

```
09-15 07:46:24.327: I/u(30804): Making Creator dynamically
09-15 07:46:24.359: W/DynamiteModule(30804): Failed to load module via V2: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$DynamiteLoaderClassLoader" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.x.y-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.x.y-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
09-15 07:46:24.363: D/ActivityManager(1195): getContentProviderImpl: from caller=android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy@734576f (pid=30804, userId=0) to get content provider com.google.android.gms.chimera cpr=ContentProviderRecord{544aa83 u0 com.google.android.gms/.chimera.container.GmsModuleProvider}
09-15 07:46:24.363: D/ActivityManager(1195): getContentProviderImpl: updateLruProcessLocked cpr.proc=ProcessRecord{11519ae 2418:com.google.android.gms.persistent/u0a12}
09-15 07:46:24.367: D/ActivityThread(30804): holder:android.app.IActivityManager$ContentProviderHolder@f2f92ce, holder.provider:android.content.ContentProviderProxy@f5075ef
09-15 07:46:24.370: I/DynamiteModule(30804): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:220
09-15 07:46:24.370: I/DynamiteModule(30804): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite, version >= 220
09-15 07:46:24.379: W/MAL-Daemon(360): event_get_last_addr(): No data available!!
09-15 07:46:24.379: I/MAL-Daemon(360): [SIM_MNGR] 1102 EN_SIM:atcmd = (AT+ESIMAPP=0,0)
09-15 07:46:24.379: W/MAL-Daemon(360): event_get_last_addr(): No data available!!
09-15 07:46:24.379: D/MAL-Daemon(360): mdmngr_task_hdl(), receive event = 101 (vendor/mediatek/proprietary/frameworks/opt/mal/entity/mdmngr/mdmngr.c:36)
09-15 07:46:24.379: D/MAL-Daemon(360): EVENT_MDMNGR_ATCMD_REQ@MDMNGR, priv_data = f6d1e900, channel = 3, cmd = (AT+ESIMAPP=0,0) (vendor/mediatek/proprietary/frameworks/opt/mal/entity/mdmngr/mdmngr.c:67)
09-15 07:46:24.379: W/MAL-Daemon(360): event_get_last_addr(): No data available!!
09-15 07:46:24.380: I/MAL-Daemon(360): mdfx_event_do_statistic(): [STATISTIC] TID = 762 has used 713762708 bytes!!
09-15 07:46:24.380: E/MAL-Daemon(360): rilproxy_task_hdl(), receive event = 401
09-15 07:46:24.380: D/MAL-Daemon(360): send ril request, request_id = 2130, serial_no = 1c35600, length = 20000000, send_size = 32(20), fd = 30
09-15 07:46:24.383: E/WifiTrafficPoller(1195): TRAFFIC_STATS_POLL true Token 85 num clients 12
09-15 07:46:24.384: E/WifiTrafficPoller(1195):  packet count Tx=91100 Rx=123247
09-15 07:46:24.384: D/MAL-Daemon(360): recv ril resp, length = 28, type = 0, result = 0, serial_no = 1c35600
09-15 07:46:24.384: D/MAL-Daemon(360): event_id = 401
09-15 07:46:24.384: D/MAL-Daemon(360): mdmngr_task_hdl(), receive event = 102 (vendor/mediatek/proprietary/frameworks/opt/mal/entity/mdmngr/mdmngr.c:36)
09-15 07:46:24.384: D/MAL-Daemon(360): EVENT_MDMNGR_ATCMD_RESP@MDMNGR (vendor/mediatek/proprietary/frameworks/opt/mal/entity/mdmngr/mdmngr.c:115)
09-15 07:46:24.384: D/MAL-Daemon(360): event_req = f6d1e900, ID = 101 (vendor/mediatek/proprietary/frameworks/opt/mal/entity/mdmngr/mdmngr.c:122)
09-15 07:46:24.384: D/MAL-Daemon(360): atcmd_resp->priv_data = f6d1e800 (vendor/mediatek/proprietary/frameworks/opt/mal/entity/mdmngr/mdmngr.c:125)
09-15 07:46:24.384: E/MAL-Daemon(360): [SIM_MNGR]  297 EN_SIM:Non cache data request()!!
09-15 07:46:24.384: I/MAL-Daemon(360): [SIM_MNGR] 1434 EN_SIM:EVENT_MDMNGR_ATCMD_RESP,event_id = 205, event_req = 0xf6d1e800, result = 1, str = (ERROR

09-15 07:46:24.384: I/MAL-Daemon(360): )
09-15 07:46:24.384: I/MAL-Daemon(360): [SIM_MNGR] 1485 EN_SIM:atcmd = (AT+ESIMAPP=0)
09-15 07:46:24.384: W/MAL-Daemon(360): event_get_last_addr(): No data available!!
09-15 07:46:24.384: D/MAL-Daemon(360): mdmngr_task_hdl(), receive event = 101 (vendor/mediatek/proprietary/frameworks/opt/mal/entity/mdmngr/mdmngr.c:36)
09-15 07:46:24.384: D/MAL-Daemon(360): EVENT_MDMNGR_ATCMD_REQ@MDMNGR, priv_data = f6d1e700, channel = 3, cmd = (AT+ESIMAPP=0) (vendor/mediatek/proprietary/frameworks/opt/mal/entity/mdmngr/mdmngr.c:67)
09-15 07:46:24.385: W/MAL-Daemon(360): event_get_last_addr(): No data available!!
09-15 07:46:24.385: I/MAL-Daemon(360): mdfx_event_do_statistic(): [STATISTIC] TID = 762 has used 713766816 bytes!!
09-15 07:46:24.385: E/MAL-Daemon(360): rilproxy_task_hdl(), receive event = 401
09-15 07:46:24.385: D/MAL-Daemon(360): send ril request, request_id = 2130, serial_no = 1c35700, length = 20000000, send_size = 32(20), fd = 30
09-15 07:46:24.385: D/WifiStateMachine(1195):  ConnectedState (when=-1ms what=131155 arg1=76!CMD_RSSI_POLL  rt=8297397/8297397 76 0 "Internal-Wifi" 14:ae:db:3c:4d:c5 rssi=-55 f=5220 sc=60 link=117 tx=10.6, 0.0, 0.0  rx=11.9 bcn=0 [on:0 tx:0 rx:0 period:3001] from screen [on:0 period:-611507583] gl hn rssi=-50 ag=0 hr ticks 0,0,25 ls-=0 [56,56,60,60,65] brc=0 lrc=0 offload-stoppedmmls=
09-15 07:46:24.385: D/WifiStateMachine(1195): Fail=0 Retry=0 MulRetry=0 ACKFail=0 FCSErr=450 TxOk=0 RxOk=17 Rst:Reason=0 Time=0 RoamFail:Times=0 Time=0 TxDone:IsARP=0 ArrDrv=0 EnQ=0 DeQ=0 LeaveDrv=0 Curr=0 CurrTime=0
09-15 07:46:24.385: D/WifiStateMachine(1195): fw log: 1 1 ScanCnt: 8 6 4 0 RoamCnt: 1 90 106 RFCnt: 44 42 0 1 1 CoexCnt: 0 0 1 LPCnt: 86942 129840 0 BBCnt: 1235 19 0 18 14 0 128 0 1214 0 50462752 41877504 MacRXCnt: 852369 263057 2 78253 235383 0 0 3975706060 327 327 327 327 327 MacTXCnt: 105645158 0 
09-15 07:46:24.386: D/WifiStateMachine(1195):  L2ConnectedState (when=-2ms what=131155 arg1=76!CMD_RSSI_POLL  rt=8297398/8297398 76 0 "Internal-Wifi" 14:ae:db:3c:4d:c5 rssi=-55 f=5220 sc=60 link=117 tx=10.6, 0.0, 0.0  rx=11.9 bcn=0 [on:0 tx:0 rx:0 period:1] from screen [on:0 period:-611507582] gl hn rssi=-50 ag=0 hr ticks 0,0,25 ls-=0 [56,56,60,60,65] brc=0 lrc=0 offload-stoppedmmls=
09-15 07:46:24.386: D/WifiStateMachine(1195): Fail=0 Retry=0 MulRetry=0 ACKFail=0 FCSErr=450 TxOk=0 RxOk=17 Rst:Reason=0 Time=0 RoamFail:Times=0 Time=0 TxDone:IsARP=0 ArrDrv=0 EnQ=0 DeQ=0 LeaveDrv=0 Curr=0 CurrTime=0
09-15 07:46:24.386: D/WifiStateMachine(1195): fw log: 1 1 ScanCnt: 8 6 4 0 RoamCnt: 1 90 106 RFCnt: 44 42 0 1 1 CoexCnt: 0 0 1 LPCnt: 86942 129840 0 BBCnt: 1235 19 0 18 14 0 128 0 1214 0 50462752 41877504 MacRXCnt: 852369 263057 2 78253 235383 0 0 3975706060 327 327 327 327 327 MacTXCnt: 105645158 0 
09-15 07:46:24.386: D/WifiStateMachine(1195):  get link layer stats 0
09-15 07:46:24.386: D/WifiHW(1195): enter -->wifi_send_command cmd=IFNAME=wlan0 SIGNAL_POLL
09-15 07:46:24.386: D/wpa_supplicant(1368): wlan0: Control interface command 'SIGNAL_POLL'
09-15 07:46:24.388: D/WifiHW(1195): leave --> reply=RSSI=-55
09-15 07:46:24.388: D/WifiHW(1195): LINKSPEED=175
09-15 07:46:24.388: D/WifiHW(1195): NOISE=9999
09-15 07:46:24.388: D/WifiHW(1195): FREQUENCY=5220
09-15 07:46:24.388: I/WifiStateMachine(1195): fetchRssiLinkSpeedAndFrequencyNative, newRssi:-55, newLinkSpeed:175, SSID:"Internal-Wifi"
09-15 07:46:24.388: D/WifiHW(1195): enter -->wifi_send_command cmd=IFNAME=wlan0 DRIVER GET_STA_LINK_DETECT
09-15 07:46:24.389: D/wpa_supplicant(1368): wlan0: Control interface command 'DRIVER GET_STA_LINK_DETECT'
09-15 07:46:24.389: D/wpa_supplicant(1368): iface wlan0 recv cmd GET_STA_LINK_DETECT
09-15 07:46:24.389: D/wpa_supplicant(1368): get_sta_link_detect
09-15 07:46:24.389: D/wpa_supplicant(1368): nl80211: Test Mode buflen = 16, ifindex=23
09-15 07:46:24.390: D/MAL-Daemon(360): recv ril resp, length = 28, type = 0, result = 0, serial_no = 1c35700
09-15 07:46:24.390: D/MAL-Daemon(360): event_id = 401
09-15 07:46:24.390: D/MAL-Daemon(360): mdmngr_task_hdl(), receive event = 102 (vendor/mediatek/proprietary/frameworks/opt/mal/entity/mdmngr/mdmngr.c:36)
09-15 07:46:24.390: D/MAL-Daemon(360): EVENT_MDMNGR_ATCMD_RESP@MDMNGR (vendor/mediatek/proprietary/frameworks/opt/mal/entity/mdmngr/mdmngr.c:115)
09-15 07:46:24.390: D/MAL-Daemon(360): event_req = f6d1e700, ID = 101 (vendor/mediatek/proprietary/frameworks/opt/mal/entity/mdmngr/mdmngr.c:122)
09-15 07:46:24.390: D/MAL-Daemon(360): atcmd_resp->priv_data = f6d1e800 (vendor/mediatek/proprietary/frameworks/opt/mal/entity/mdmngr/mdmngr.c:125)
09-15 07:46:24.390: E/MAL-Daemon(360): [SIM_MNGR]  297 EN_SIM:Non cache data request()!!
09-15 07:46:24.390: I/MAL-Daemon(360): [SIM_MNGR] 1434 EN_SIM:EVENT_MDMNGR_ATCMD_RESP,event_id = 205, event_req = 0xf6d1e800, result = 1, str = (ERROR

09-15 07:46:24.390: I/MAL-Daemon(360): )
09-15 07:46:24.390: W/MAL-Daemon(360): [SIM_MNGR]  185 EN_SIM:simmngr_cache_load() SIM Type need retry result=1!!
09-15 07:46:24.390: D/WifiHW(1195): leave --> reply=
09-15 07:46:24.390: D/WifiHW(1195): Fail=0 Retry=0 MulRetry=0 ACKFail=0 FCSErr=389 TxOk=0 RxOk=67 Rst:Reason=0 Time=0 RoamFail:Times=0 Time=0 TxDone:IsARP=0 ArrDrv=0 EnQ=0 DeQ=0 LeaveDrv=0 Curr=0 CurrTime=0
09-15 07:46:24.390: D/WifiHW(1195): fw log: 1 1 ScanCnt: 8 6 4 0 RoamCnt: 1 90 106 RFCnt: 44 42 0 1 1 CoexCnt: 0 0 1 LPCnt: 86942 129840 2 BBCnt: 2008 15 0 15 34 0 187 0 1961 0 50462752 41877504 MacRXCnt: 853256 263446 2 78320 235645 0 0 3978713915 622 622 622 622 622 MacTXCnt: 105710693 0 
09-15 07:46:24.391: E/WifiStateMachine(1195): wifiLinkStatics=
09-15 07:46:24.391: E/WifiStateMachine(1195): Fail=0 Retry=0 MulRetry=0 ACKFail=0 FCSErr=389 TxOk=0 RxOk=67 Rst:Reason=0 Time=0 RoamFail:Times=0 Time=0 TxDone:IsARP=0 ArrDrv=0 EnQ=0 DeQ=0 LeaveDrv=0 Curr=0 CurrTime=0
09-15 07:46:24.391: E/WifiStateMachine(1195): fw log: 1 1 ScanCnt: 8 6 4 0 RoamCnt: 1 90 106 RFCnt: 44 42 0 1 1 CoexCnt: 0 0 1 LPCnt: 86942 129840 2 BBCnt: 2008 15 0 15 34 0 187 0 1961 0 50462752 41877504 MacRXCnt: 853256 263446 2 78320 235645 0 0 3978713915 622 622 622 622 622 MacTXCnt: 105710693 0 
09-15 07:46:24.391: D/WifiStateMachine(1195): mLastSignalLevel:4, newSignalLevel:4
09-15 07:46:24.391: E/WifiConfigStore(1195): updateConfiguration freq=5220 BSSID=14:ae:db:3c:4d:c5 RSSI=-54 "Internal-Wifi"-WPA_PSK
09-15 07:46:24.391: V/ActivityManager(1195): Broadcast sticky: ******** ordered=false userid=-1 callerApp=ProcessRecord{9c8c33c 1195:system/1000}
09-15 07:46:24.392: D/WifiWatchdogStateMachine(1195): RSSI current: 4 new: -55, 4
09-15 07:46:24.392: D/StatusBar.NetworkController(1424): slot=-10;action=android.net.wifi.RSSI_CHANGED
09-15 07:46:24.393: D/StatusBar.NetworkController(1424): updateNetworkName slotId=0 chosenNetType=3 mNetworkName=JAWWAL mNetworkTypeName=3G
09-15 07:46:24.393: D/StatusBar.NetworkController(1424): updateNetworkName slotId=1 chosenNetType=1 mNetworkName=JAWWAL mNetworkTypeName=
09-15 07:46:24.436: I/Google Maps Android API(30804): Google Play services client version: 9452000
09-15 07:46:24.439: I/Google Maps Android API(30804): Google Play services package version: 13280021
09-15 07:46:24.490: W/MAL-Daemon(360): event_get_last_addr(): No data available!!
09-15 07:46:24.490: I/MAL-Daemon(360): [SIM_MNGR] 1102 EN_SIM:atcmd = (AT+ESIMAPP=0,0)
09-15 07:46:24.490: W/MAL-Daemon(360): event_get_last_addr(): No data available!!
09-15 07:46:24.491: D/MAL-Daemon(360): mdmngr_task_hdl(), receive event = 101 (vendor/mediatek/proprietary/frameworks/opt/mal/entity/mdmngr/mdmngr.c:36)
09-15 07:46:24.491: D/MAL-Daemon(360): EVENT_MDMNGR_ATCMD_REQ@MDMNGR, priv_data = f6d1e780, channel = 3, cmd = (AT+ESIMAPP=0,0) (vendor/mediatek/proprietary/frameworks/opt/mal/entity/mdmngr/mdmngr.c:67)
09-15 07:46:24.491: W/MAL-Daemon(360): event_get_last_addr(): No data available!!
09-15 07:46:24.491: I/MAL-Daemon(360): mdfx_event_do_statistic(): [STATISTIC] TID = 762 has used 713770924 bytes!!
09-15 07:46:24.491: E/MAL-Daemon(360): rilproxy_task_hdl(), receive event = 401
09-15 07:46:24.491: D/MAL-Daemon(360): send ril request, request_id = 2130, serial_no = 1c35800, length = 20000000, send_size = 32(20), fd = 30
09-15 07:46:24.494: I/System.out(30804): Failed to initialize, google play services not installed: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
09-15 07:46:24.494: W/System.err(30804): java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
09-15 07:46:24.494: W/System.err(30804):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.q.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280051@13.2.80 (040408-211705629):12)
09-15 07:46:24.494: W/System.err(30804):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.auth.e.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280051@13.2.80 (040408-211705629):17)
09-15 07:46:24.494: W/System.err(30804):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.e.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280051@13.2.80 (040408-211705629):5)
09-15 07:46:24.494: W/System.err(30804):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.b.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280051@13.2.80 (040408-211705629):14)
09-15 07:46:24.494: W/System.err(30804):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280051@13.2.80 (040408-211705629):13)
09-15 07:46:24.494: W/System.err(30804):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapViewDelegate(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280051@13.2.80 (040408-211705629):51)
09-15 07:46:24.494: D/MAL-Daemon(360): recv ril resp, length = 28, type = 0, result = 0, serial_no = 1c35800
09-15 07:46:24.494: W/System.err(30804):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.i.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280051@13.2.80 (040408-211705629):77)
09-15 07:46:24.495: D/MAL-Daemon(360): event_id = 401
09-15 07:46:24.495: W/System.err(30804):    at fh.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280051@13.2.80 (040408-211705629):10)
09-15 07:46:24.495: W/System.err(30804):    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:392)
09-15 07:46:24.495: W/System.err(30804):    at cgu.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280021@13.2.80 (040408-211705629):2)
09-15 07:46:24.495: D/MAL-Daemon(360): mdmngr_task_hdl(), receive event = 102 (vendor/mediatek/proprietary/frameworks/opt/mal/entity/mdmngr/mdmngr.c:36)
09-15 07:46:24.495: W/System.err(30804):    at acfh.newMapViewDelegate(:com.google.android.gms@13280021@13.2.80 (040408-211705629):1)
09-15 07:46:24.495: D/MAL-Daemon(360): EVENT_MDMNGR_ATCMD_RESP@MDMNGR (vendor/mediatek/proprietary/frameworks/opt/mal/entity/mdmngr/mdmngr.c:115)
09-15 07:46:24.495: D/MAL-Daemon(360): event_req = f6d1e780, ID = 101 (vendor/mediatek/proprietary/frameworks/opt/mal/entity/mdmngr/mdmngr.c:122)
09-15 07:46:24.495: W/System.err(30804):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapViewDelegate(:com.google.android.gms@13280021@13.2.80 (040408-211705629):2)
09-15 07:46:24.495: D/MAL-Daemon(360): atcmd_resp->priv_data = f6d1e900 (vendor/mediatek/proprietary/frameworks/opt/mal/entity/mdmngr/mdmngr.c:125)
09-15 07:46:24.495: W/System.err(30804):    at acfg.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280021@13.2.80 (040408-211705629):39)
09-15 07:46:24.495: W/System.err(30804):    at cgv.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@13280021@13.2.80 (040408-211705629):4)
09-15 07:46:24.495: W/System.err(30804):    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:392)
09-15 07:46:24.495: W/System.err(30804):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.a.w$a$a.a(Unknown Source)
09-15 07:46:24.495: E/MAL-Daemon(360): [SIM_MNGR]  297 EN_SIM:Non cache data request()!!
09-15 07:46:24.495: W/System.err(30804):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$b.f(Unknown Source)
09-15 07:46:24.495: I/MAL-Daemon(360): [SIM_MNGR] 1434 EN_SIM:EVENT_MDMNGR_ATCMD_RESP,event_id = 205, event_req = 0xf6d1e900, result = 1, str = (ERROR

09-15 07:46:24.495: I/MAL-Daemon(360): )
09-15 07:46:24.495: W/System.err(30804):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$b.a(Unknown Source)
09-15 07:46:24.495: I/MAL-Daemon(360): [SIM_MNGR] 1485 EN_SIM:atcmd = (AT+ESIMAPP=0)
09-15 07:46:24.495: W/System.err(30804):    at com.google.android.gms.a.b.a(Unknown Source)
09-15 07:46:24.495: W/System.err(30804):    at com.google.android.gms.a.b.a(Unknown Source)
09-15 07:46:24.495: W/MAL-Daemon(360): event_get_last_addr(): No data available!!
09-15 07:46:24.495: W/System.err(30804):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.a(Unknown Source)
09-15 07:46:24.495: W/System.err(30804):    at com.codename1.h.b.o(InternalNativeMapsImpl.java:256)
09-15 07:46:24.495: D/MAL-Daemon(360): mdmngr_task_hdl(), receive event = 101 (vendor/mediatek/proprietary/frameworks/opt/mal/entity/mdmngr/mdmngr.c:36)
09-15 07:46:24.495: W/System.err(30804):    at com.codename1.h.b.n(InternalNativeMapsImpl.java:55)
09-15 07:46:24.495: D/MAL-Daemon(360): EVENT_MDMNGR_ATCMD_REQ@MDMNGR, priv_data = f6d1e700, channel = 3, cmd = (AT+ESIMAPP=0) (vendor/mediatek/proprietary/frameworks/opt/mal/entity/mdmngr/mdmngr.c:67)
09-15 07:46:24.495: W/System.err(30804):    at com.codename1.h.b$1.run(InternalNativeMapsImpl.java:78)
09-15 07:46:24.495: W/MAL-Daemon(360): event_get_last_addr(): No data available!!
09-15 07:46:24.495: W/System.err(30804):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
09-15 07:46:24.495: W/System.err(30804):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
09-15 07:46:24.495: W/System.err(30804):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
09-15 07:46:24.495: I/MAL-Daemon(360): mdfx_event_do_statistic(): [STATISTIC] TID = 762 has used 713775032 bytes!!
09-15 07:46:24.495: W/System.err(30804):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5856)
09-15 07:46:24.495: E/MAL-Daemon(360): rilproxy_task_hdl(), receive event = 401
09-15 07:46:24.495: W/System.err(30804):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-15 07:46:24.495: D/MAL-Daemon(360): send ril request, request_id = 2130, serial_no = 1c35900, length = 20000000, send_size = 32(20), fd = 30
09-15 07:46:24.495: W/System.err(30804):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:933)
09-15 07:46:24.495: W/System.err(30804):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:782)
09-15 07:46:24.497: I/Google Maps Android API(30804): Google Play services package version: 13280021
09-15 07:46:24.499: I/System.out(30804): Failed to initialize, google play services not installed: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
09-15 07:46:24.499: W/System.err(30804): java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
09-15 07:46:24.499: W/System.err(30804):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.q.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280051@13.2.80 (040408-211705629):12)
09-15 07:46:24.499: W/System.err(30804):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.auth.e.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280051@13.2.80 (040408-211705629):17)
09-15 07:46:24.499: D/MAL-Daemon(360): recv ril resp, length = 28, type = 0, result = 0, serial_no = 1c35900
09-15 07:46:24.499: D/MAL-Daemon(360): event_id = 401
09-15 07:46:24.499: W/System.err(30804):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.e.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280051@13.2.80 (040408-211705629):5)
09-15 07:46:24.499: W/System.err(30804):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.b.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280051@13.2.80 (040408-211705629):14)
09-15 07:46:24.499: W/System.err(30804):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280051@13.2.80 (040408-211705629):13)
09-15 07:46:24.499: W/System.err(30804):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapViewDelegate(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280051@13.2.80 (040408-211705629):51)
09-15 07:46:24.499: D/MAL-Daemon(360): mdmngr_task_hdl(), receive event = 102 (vendor/mediatek/proprietary/frameworks/opt/mal/entity/mdmngr/mdmngr.c:36)
09-15 07:46:24.499: W/System.err(30804):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.i.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280051@13.2.80 (040408-211705629):77)
09-15 07:46:24.499: D/MAL-Daemon(360): EVENT_MDMNGR_ATCMD_RESP@MDMNGR (vendor/mediatek/proprietary/frameworks/opt/mal/entity/mdmngr/mdmngr.c:115)
09-15 07:46:24.499: D/MAL-Daemon(360): event_req = f6d1e700, ID = 101 (vendor/mediatek/proprietary/frameworks/opt/mal/entity/mdmngr/mdmngr.c:122)
09-15 07:46:24.499: D/MAL-Daemon(360): atcmd_resp->priv_data = f6d1e900 (vendor/mediatek/proprietary/frameworks/opt/mal/entity/mdmngr/mdmngr.c:125)
09-15 07:46:24.499: W/System.err(30804):    at fh.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280051@13.2.80 (040408-211705629):10)
09-15 07:46:24.500: W/System.err(30804):    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:392)
09-15 07:46:24.500: E/MAL-Daemon(360): [SIM_MNGR]  297 EN_SIM:Non cache data request()!!
09-15 07:46:24.500: W/System.err(30804):    at cgu.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280021@13.2.80 (040408-211705629):2)
09-15 07:46:24.500: I/MAL-Daemon(360): [SIM_MNGR] 1434 EN_SIM:EVENT_MDMNGR_ATCMD_RESP,event_id = 205, event_req = 0xf6d1e900, result = 1, str = (ERROR

09-15 07:46:24.500: I/MAL-Daemon(360): )
09-15 07:46:24.500: W/System.err(30804):    at acfh.newMapViewDelegate(:com.google.android.gms@13280021@13.2.80 (040408-211705629):1)
09-15 07:46:24.500: W/System.err(30804):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapViewDelegate(:com.google.android.gms@13280021@13.2.80 (040408-211705629):2)
09-15 07:46:24.500: W/System.err(30804):    at acfg.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280021@13.2.80 (040408-211705629):39)
09-15 07:46:24.500: W/System.err(30804):    at cgv.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@13280021@13.2.80 (040408-211705629):4)
09-15 07:46:24.500: W/MAL-Daemon(360): [SIM_MNGR]  185 EN_SIM:simmngr_cache_load() SIM Type need retry result=1!!
09-15 07:46:24.500: W/System.err(30804):    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:392)
09-15 07:46:24.500: W/System.err(30804):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.a.w$a$a.a(Unknown Source)
09-15 07:46:24.500: W/System.err(30804):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$b.f(Unknown Source)
09-15 07:46:24.500: W/System.err(30804):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$b.a(Unknown Source)
09-15 07:46:24.500: W/System.err(30804):    at com.google.android.gms.a.b.a(Unknown Source)
09-15 07:46:24.500: W/System.err(30804):    at com.google.android.gms.a.b.a(Unknown Source)
09-15 07:46:24.500: W/System.err(30804):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.a(Unknown Source)
09-15 07:46:24.500: W/System.err(30804):    at com.codename1.h.b$4.run(InternalNativeMapsImpl.java:514)
09-15 07:46:24.500: W/System.err(30804):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
09-15 07:46:24.500: W/System.err(30804):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
09-15 07:46:24.500: W/System.err(30804):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
09-15 07:46:24.500: W/System.err(30804):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5856)
09-15 07:46:24.500: W/System.err(30804):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-15 07:46:24.500: W/System.err(30804):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:933)
09-15 07:46:24.500: W/System.err(30804):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:782)
09-15 07:46:24.512: W/System.err(30804): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.codename1.t.g.f com.codename1.t.l.W()' on a null object reference
09-15 07:46:24.512: W/System.err(30804):    at com.codename1.t.m.g(ComponentSelector.java:1785)
09-15 07:46:24.512: W/System.err(30804):    at com.codename1.t.m.c(ComponentSelector.java:1733)
09-15 07:46:24.512: W/System.err(30804):    at com.codename1.h.d.<init>(MapContainer.java:200)
09-15 07:46:24.512: W/System.err(30804):    at com.codename1.h.d.<init>(MapContainer.java:163)
09-15 07:46:24.512: W/System.err(30804):    at b.a.bo(Unknown Source)
09-15 07:46:24.512: W/System.err(30804):    at a.a.f(Unknown Source)
09-15 07:46:24.512: W/System.err(30804):    at com.codename1.t.l.f.a(UIBuilder.java:2518)
09-15 07:46:24.512: W/System.err(30804):    at com.codename1.t.l.f.a(UIBuilder.java:2565)
09-15 07:46:24.512: W/System.err(30804):    at b.a.iI(Unknown Source)
09-15 07:46:24.512: W/System.err(30804):    at a.a.a(Unknown Source)
09-15 07:46:24.512: W/System.err(30804):    at com.codename1.t.l.f$a.a(UIBuilder.java:2835)
09-15 07:46:24.512: W/System.err(30804):    at com.codename1.t.l.c.a(EventDispatcher.java:349)
09-15 07:46:24.512: W/System.err(30804):    at com.codename1.t.d.f(Button.java:570)
09-15 07:46:24.512: W/System.err(30804):    at com.codename1.t.d.g(Button.java:604)
09-15 07:46:24.512: W/System.err(30804):    at com.codename1.t.d.b(Button.java:708)
09-15 07:46:24.512: W/System.err(30804):    at com.codename1.t.u.b(Form.java:3259)
09-15 07:46:24.512: W/System.err(30804):    at com.codename1.t.l.f(Component.java:4288)
09-15 07:46:24.512: W/System.err(30804):    at com.codename1.t.q.a(Display.java:2065)
09-15 07:46:24.512: W/System.err(30804):    at com.codename1.t.q.j(Display.java:1043)
09-15 07:46:24.512: W/System.err(30804):    at com.codename1.t.q.i(Display.java:961)
09-15 07:46:24.512: W/System.err(30804):    at com.codename1.t.ai.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
09-15 07:46:24.512: W/System.err(30804):    at com.codename1.impl.b$1.run(CodenameOneThread.java:60)
09-15 07:46:24.513: W/System.err(30804):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

as for the code :

simple one I have a list of coordinates that I add like this :

```
final String HTML_API_KEY = "AI_____________________";
final MapContainer cnt = new MapContainer(HTML_API_KEY);

double la = position.getLatitude();
double lon = position.getLongitude();
cnt.addMarker(EncodedImage.createFromImage(currentMarkerImg, false), new Coord(la, lon), "", "", e3->{
    ToastBar.showMessage("Current Location ", FontImage.MATERIAL_PLACE);
});
cnt.setCameraPosition(new Coord(la, lon));
cnt.zoom(new Coord(la, lon), 15);
```

and here is the configuration that I added to codenameone.settings :

```
android.xapplication=<meta-data android\:name\="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android\:value\="AI_____________________"/>
android.xapplication_attr=<meta-data android\:name\="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android\:value\="AI_____________________"/>
javascript.googlemaps.key=AI_____________________
codename1.arg.javascript.googlemaps.key=AI_____________________
```

I can't find what is missing or what cause of error on the application , the exception is straight forward , I tried to add the xapplication_attr to include the api key in the application tag in the manifest but still the same error

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions say you should add them to the build hints not to `codenameone_settings.properties`. When you add to the build hints some characters such as `:` and `=` are escaped correctly.

But more importantly a build hint has the prefix `codename1.arg.` prepended to it. I see you only did that for the javascript instruction.

Comment: I have questions about the native map solution , can the solution be used on offline manner , plus I have noticed that some times on android devices the map just get blank and you need to exit the frame and get back to it to see it again